# Android: FragmentManager version mismatch

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a strange problem in Android. I am using `Fragment`s and `FragmentActivity`s from the `android.support.v4.app` packages. However, it seems like `FragmentActivity.getFragmentManager()`'s returns an object of the type `android.app.FragmentManager` instead of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`. The former is incompatible with the `v4` Fragments, which causes me to have trouble using anything at all. For instance, the following code gives type mismatches:

```
// "this" is a FragmentActivity, "frag" is a Fragment -- both from the v4 packages
FragmentManager fm = this.getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, frag)
    .commit();
```

This returns a type mismatch exception, because the `replace()` method does not accept a `v4` Fragment as argument.

Any thoughts on how to solve this strange problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
this.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

instead of:

```
this.getFragmentManager();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

FragmentActivity is from support.v4 jar so in case of FragmentActivity you will have to choose supportFragmentManager and in case of Activity you can get FragmentManager directly same is with fragment transaction.

Thanks
Ankur